# How wp-cron can run in background if PHP is single threaded?

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-cron, cron, threading

I read that wp-cron runs when a page load request comes. So, if PHP is single threaded how can all the cron jobs run as a separate task?

If that's not the case, may anyone please help to understand the implementation that runs the cron job and also sends the response without making the client wait for cron job to finish?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

Comment: the cron laucher send a asynchronous HTTP request and continue the page loading. then the page loading is not decelerated and the cron job run in background on another PHP thread. look this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125995/do-wordpress-cron-jobs-slow-down-page-loading?rq=1

Comment: So is there two requests(one synchronous that is for page load & another asynchronous that you mentioned) on every page load? How is this cron launcher triggered? Is it triggered after processing page load request or before that?

Comment: the function `wp_cron` which launches the HTTP request is hooked at the action `init`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. One more question, is there a separate async HTTP request for every cron job in the cron_array or single Async HTTP request that runs all scheduled cron jobs one by one?

Comment: there is no such thing. one task -> lock -> task done -> lock release -> check for next job.